# Cassandra : how to prevent and debug node going Out Of Memory?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

I have Cassandra nodes that go regularly out of memory, and it is difficult to find out why.

**Questions**

- could you list the things I have to check to avoid a node going out of memory ?
- how to debug when a node go out of memory ?

Thank you

Comment: What is the size of the Java heap?  I've seen folks out here recently trying to run Cassandra on a  heap <= 4GB, and that's difficult to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to tell exact root cause without heap dump or error logs   please set up heap dump

follow [link](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/3.x/cassandra/configuration/configHeapDump.html) then only we can get actual reason .

**Some possible reason**

Your rows are probably growing too big to fit in RAM when it comes time to compact them. A compaction requires the entire row to fit in RAM.

There's also a hard limit of 2 billion columns per row but in reality you shouldn't ever let rows grow that wide. Bucket them by adding a day or server name or some other value common across your dataset to your row keys.

For a "write-often read-almost-never" workload you can have very wide rows but you shouldn't come close to the 2 billion column mark. Keep it in millions with bucketing.

For a write/read mixed workload where you're reading entire rows frequently even hundreds of columns may be too much.

Comment: I use LCS. And I have indeed some large rows (about 60MB each). The heap is 32GB. So a single row is likely to fit in RAM. But how many rows need to be in memory at once, while compacting a table ? For instance, I have with `compactionhistory` for that table (with wide rows), `rows_merged` = `{1:2898, 2:24408}`. Does it means that 2898 need to go into memory at once ? Thank you.